# Cannot reorder column by vector of column indices referred by ncol

Tags: r, data.table

I have some simple data frames of n columns.
For each of them, I want to move the last column to the first.
Since number of columns is variable, I used:

```
df <- df[, c(ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df)-1))]
```

=========================================================

However, I do not understand why both `c(12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)` and `c(ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df)-1))` returns

> [1] 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

and `df[, c(12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)]` can return the reordered table I want,

but

```
df[, c(ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df)-1))]
```

returns the above vector of indices instead of the reordered table

Thanks!

===============================================================

EDIT:

reproducible example below:

```
df <- data.table(v1=c(1,2), v2=c(3,4), v3=c(5,6))

c(3,1,2)
c(ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df)-1))

df2 <- df[, c(3,1,2)]
df2
df3 <- df[, c(ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df)-1))]
df3
```

Comment: Please share a reproducible example

Comment: In ?data.table, check out the with= argument. Also consider ?setcolorder

Comment: @docendodiscimus reproducible example added

Comment: Since you're dealing with `data.table`s, the comment by Frank is spot on. You might want to read the introduction where this is explained very early, iirc

Comment: Thanks a lot! While I am still figuring out the mechanism, at least now I know what I need is `with = False`.